# How to structure subclasses with mypy for typing

Tags: python, subclass, type-hinting, mypy

Say I already have a file with a class that is correctly typed:

```
#main.py

class Runner(object):
    ...
    def operation(self, arg: str) -> Runner:
        self.attrib = 'something ' + arg 
        return self
    ...
```

Now I want to separate many of these `operation` methods sicen my file is becoming too large, so I create a new file `subs.py` and transfer my code to a mixing:

```
#main.py

from subs import Mixin
class Runner(Mixin):
    ...

#subs.py

class Mixin(object):
    ...
    def operation(self, arg: str) -> Runner:
        self.attrib = 'something ' + arg 
        return self
```

The `Runner` Type is unknowm to `subs.py` and if I import it then I will be creating circular import dependency, and I dont even think it will work anyway, so Im not sure the correct way to deal with this, in the assumed case that :class:`Mixin` will **only** ever be used inherited by the main class.

Comment: I wouldn't split the definition up just because your file is large. A large class isn't automatically *too* large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you move the method into the class `Mixin`, you *don't* know that `operation` will return an instance of `Runner`. Consider:

```
class Foo(Bar, Mixin):
    ...

f = Foo()
f.operation()  # Returns something that is a Bar and a Mixin, but not a Runner.
```

The correct type hint is

```
def operation(self, arg: str) -> Mixin:
    self.attrib = 'something ' + arg
    return self
```